# EJB 3.0 Managed bean injecting and db connection closing

Tags: java, jdbc, ejb-3.0, cdi, jboss6.x

In the ejb 3.0 jboss 6 environment, I have a bean called DBInterface that is injected into many dao classes to execute the sql queries. the DBInterface bean has the datasource injected as a field variable. all the methods inside the DBInterface bean gets the database connection from the injected datasource and closes the connection after processing the db-calls. while running the application, after some amount of time, I get sql exception saying cannot create db connection. I am closing the connection on every method calls in the finally block. where am I making the error? I use ejb 3.0 in the jboss. 
regards
V

```
public class DBInterface {
   @Resource(mappedName = "java:ora.ds", type = DataSource.class)
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    protected Connection getConnection(){
        try {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printstacktrace();
       }
    }
    public void method1() {
      Connection connection = null;
         try {
               connection = getConnection();
                ...............
                 db codes
                .................
         } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        throw new DBException("sql exception ", e);
        } finally {
             try {
                    closeResources(rs, statement, connection);
             } catch (SQLException e) {
                  logger.error(e);
                    throw new DBException("sql exception ", e);
           }
       }
    }
    public void closeResources(ResultSet rs, Statement st, Connection con)
        throws SQLException {
           if (rs != null) {
             rs.close();
           }
          if (st != null) {
                 st.close();
           }
          if (con != null) {
           con.close();
         }

       }
}
```

Comment: Dont inject  a datasource to static field...

Comment: also be sure to close resources in separate try-catch blocks

Comment: Yes you are right, I no more use the static for the datasource. Sorry I pasted here the old testing code.
What do you mean by the separate try-catch block? I there anyother mistake that I am not seeing in this code?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer since I can't post code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using try-catch blocks for closing any resources.

```
if (rs != null) {
    rs.close();
}
if (st != null) {
    st.close();
}
if (con != null) {
    con.close();
}
```

Should be replaced with:

```
if (rs != null) {
    try {
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.log("Failed to close ResultSet", exception);
    }
}
if (st != null) {
    try {
        st.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.log("Failed to close Statement", exception);
    }
}
if (con != null) {
    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        logger.log("Failed to close Connection", exception);
    }
}
```

This can be refactored to something that is easier to read using AbstractDAO class:

```
public class DAOException extends RuntimeException {
    public DAOException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractDAO {
    private static Logger logger = ...;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    protected void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            // There's nothing we can do
            throw new DAOException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // Log the exception
            logger.log("Failed to close Connection", exception);
        }
    }

    public void close(Statement statement) {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // Log the exception
            logger.log("Failed to close Statement", exception);
        }
    }

    public void close(ResultSet resultSet) {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            // Log the exception
            logger.log("Failed to close ResultSet", exception);
        }
    }
}

public class MyDAO extends AbstractDAO {
    @Override
    @Resource("jdbc/myDS")
    protected void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public void insert(MyObject myObject) {
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement query = connection.createPreparedStatement("INSERT INTO MYOBJECT (ID, VALUE) VALUES (?, ?)");
            try {
                query.setLong(1, myObject.getID());
                query.setString(2, myObject.getValue());
                if (query.executeUpdate() != 1) {
                    throw new DAOException("ExecuteUpdate did not return expected result");
                }
            } finally {
                close(query);
            }
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            // There's nothing we can do
            throw new DAOException(exception);
        } finally {
            close(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is that why aren't you using JPA? I would considering using JDBC only for performance critical applications that do not benefit from caching.

Comment: The reason I do not use the JPA is due the data complication that is periodically updated by and from the 3rd party. So I need to use queries in few places where the JPA help me not.

Comment: I would propapbly use views rather than updating sql-queries every time table structures change.